# Reset svg fill in css

Tags: css, svg, hover, fill

I want to have all my svgs to have the same plain color. So I use

```
svg *{
   fill: #ccc;
}
```

But I want to get default fills on :hover. How can I disable the fills and get defaults back?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using `:not()` and effectively style "not hovered".

```
svg *:not(:hover){
  fill: #ccc;
}
```

The above might work, here's a quick CodePen that you can play with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrqyAx

You can learn more on the [Mozilla Dveloper Network entry for :not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Alternatively (I was curious) you could use fill:inherit - which is just as valid. In this case, the color used will be inherited from the fill value of the parent svg, which can be set in css also.

```
svg *:hover{
  fill : inherit;
}
```

I've added an svg styled in this manner to the CodePen.

Comment: In regards to your second comment, `fill:inherit` will simply return the colour back to the default SVG colour; which 9 times out of 10 is black. It won't return the colours to the original fill colours of the SVG before it was altered. See [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POZXgg) where the original `<polyline>` is `pink`. Hovering merely turns it to its inherited SVG default colour of `black`.

Comment: @shennan that's what I think was asked, though I agree that this is a worthwhile clarification for others finding this answer.

Comment: `inherit` is not a valid value for `fill`